# rectangles with labels to xml python

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

My problem has to do with object detection, where I have a list of rectangles coordinates inside an image and the labeling in another list and a original image, like this:

```
print(original_image.shape)
(720, 1280,3)

rectangles = [[100,200,40,100],[200,400,80,170]] 
labels = [0,1]
```

To train a model with tensorflow people usually, use some kind of software to label the images that generate an xml file that you can use in tensorflow. Is it possible to use what I have instead?

Comment: you should look at this tutorial. This will enlighten you http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html

Comment: This is very different from what I want, I don't want to classify an image, I want to detect an object inside of an image.

Comment: I'm afraid it is exactly the same problem when applied to your question

Comment: No, because in the exercise you propose the model learns out of the values in the rectangles vector, where in my case the values do not matter. What matters is the output of the cut in the image that the coordinates of the rectangles originate.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your list into a Pascal VOC xml format by using pythons `xml.etree.cElementTree`. Do something like this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('annotation')

ET.SubElement(root, 'folder').text = 'images' # set correct folder name
ET.SubElement(root, 'filename').text = img_filename

size = ET.SubElement(root, 'size')
ET.SubElement(size, 'width').text = str(img_width)
ET.SubElement(size, 'height').text = str(img_height)
ET.SubElement(size, 'depth').text = str(img_depth)

ET.SubElement(root, 'segmented').text = '0'

for box in rectangles:
    name = # class name
    xmin = box[] #set correct index
    ymin = box[] #set correct index
    xmax = box[] #set correct index
    ymax = box[] #set correct index

    obj = ET.SubElement(root, 'object')
    ET.SubElement(obj, 'name').text = name
    ET.SubElement(obj, 'pose').text = 'Unspecified'
    ET.SubElement(obj, 'truncated').text = '0'
    ET.SubElement(obj, 'occluded').text = '0'
    ET.SubElement(obj, 'difficult').text = '0'

    bx = ET.SubElement(obj, 'bndbox')
    ET.SubElement(bx, 'xmin').text = str(xmin)
    ET.SubElement(bx, 'ymin').text = str(ymin)
    ET.SubElement(bx, 'xmax').text = str(xmax)
    ET.SubElement(bx, 'ymax').text = str(ymax)


tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(file_write_path)
```